# Git: commits by order of merge

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have written a python script that iterates through the last 10 commits in my master branch. Master branch is restricted from commit and can only be merged to.

Consider the below scenario.

Branch 1 has a commit done at 10.00 am with commits 1 & 2
Branch 2 has a commit done at 11.00 am with commits 3 & 4.

I merged branch 2 before branch 1 to master.

Now when I print the commits while iterating it still prints 4 & 3 followed by 2 & 1.

I need to iterate in the order of latest commit merged to master first. Ie. I need it as 2, 1, 4 & 3. Is this possible?

Comment: It will be easier for us to help you if you post your current working code that gives you `4 3 2 1` order of commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sort options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering) for `git log` are:

- `--date-order`
- `--author-date-order`
- `--topo-order`
- `--reverse`

In your case `--topo-order` will do the job:

```
> git log --topo-order --no-merges --format="%ad -- %s"
2019-03-12 18:05:02 -- c2 (topic1)
2019-03-12 18:04:59 -- c1 (topic1)
2019-03-12 18:05:22 -- c4 (topic2)
2019-03-12 18:05:19 -- c3 (topic2)
2019-03-12 18:04:47 -- commit on master
```